# Maven plugin to create Java executable

Tags: package, maven-plugin, executable-jar

I am trying to create an Executable jar that includes all my classes and the dependent JARs. I tried multiple maven plugins, but not successful. One of the options "jar-with-dependencies" adds all the dependencies, but the dependent JARs are exploded.

What I want is

```
<MyMain>
   <META-INF>
       MANIFEST.MF //containing MAIN class and Classpath with all the dependencies.
   <com>
   <lib> 
        spring-core-3.0.jar
        spring-beans-3.0.jar 
        // and all dependent jars underneath
```

I tried the following, but to no avail. It creates a proper MANIFEST but doesn't copy all the jars.

```
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes/lib</outputDirectory>
                        <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>MyMainClass</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
```

I use Spring Tool Suite and run->maven install

Answer (score 0):

You can use the assembly plugin:

```
<plugin>
  <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
     <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
  </configuration>
 </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. I believe I used the assembly plugin too, but it exploded my dependent JARs as opposed to copying them as is to the lib folder.

Comment: What do you mean by exploded?

Comment: extracted all the files and created the folder/file structure within my main JAR.

Comment: Updated my original post. I use Spring Tool Suite and run->maven install

Comment: Can you add an image of how the structure looks. I wanna understand what exploding mean.

Comment: Sorry...how do I add an image? Can't seem to find an option.

Comment: Exploded JAR:`<MyMain>
       <META-INF>
           MANIFEST.MF //containing MAIN class and Classpath with all the dependencies.
       <com>
       <org> 
         <spring-framework>
            <beans>BeanUtils.class`